# Memoir equivalent of "\endnotemark"?

Tags: memoir, enotez

I'm trying to migrate from using *enotez* to only the referencing options in *memoir*.  Unfortunately, no matter how much I stare at the *memoir* manual, I can't grasp how to get the same effect as the "\endnotemark" command from *enotez*.

My attempt at creating an equivalent command has met with strange results, which look to me like something to do with interpreting the counter.  Instead of a single number for each reference (e.g., "35"), it's giving me a number-dot-number result (e.g., "2.2").  Prior to stripping it down to a MWE, it was giving me partially-spelled numbers in the references, such as "Two.1".

I'm baffled.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\makepagenote
\continuousnotenums

\newcommand{\pagenotemark}[1][]{\notenumintext{#1}}
\let\endnotemark=\pagenotemark
\let\endnote=\pagenote

\renewcommand{\notenumintext}[1]{{\color{red}\textsuperscript{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

    \section{First Section}

        Text.\endnote{Endnote one.}\label{X}

    \section{Second Section}

        Text.\endnotemark[\ref{X}]

\chapter{Second Chapter}

    \section{Third Section}

        Text.\endnotemark[\ref{X}]

    \section{Fourth Section}

        More text.\endnote{Endnote two}\label{Y}

    \section{Fifth Section}

        More text.\endnotemark[\ref{Y}]

\printpagenotes

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with `\footnote` you have to put the `\label` *inside* the `\endnote` argument. There is a group and outside you are not getting the label from the note but from the section.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\makepagenote
\continuousnotenums

\newcommand{\pagenotemark}[1][]{\notenumintext{#1}}
\let\endnotemark=\pagenotemark
\let\endnote=\pagenote

\renewcommand{\notenumintext}[1]{{\color{red}\textsuperscript{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}

    \section{First Section}

        Text.\endnote{Endnote one.\label{X}}

    \section{Second Section}

        Text.\endnotemark[\ref{X}]

\chapter{Second Chapter}

    \section{Third Section}

        Text.\endnotemark[\ref{X}]

    \section{Fourth Section}

        More text.\endnote{Endnote two\label{Y}}

    \section{Fifth Section}

        More text.\endnotemark[\ref{Y}]

\printpagenotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  I was aware that it had to be inside for footnotes, but outside for endnotes, so it didn't occur to me to check if that had somehow changed.  (Boy, do I feel silly!)  Is it that memoir handles things differently, so all such references are inside?  I guess that means I'll have to edit hundreds (if not thousands) of notes -- but that raises another question:  Now that I have to make those changes, would it be best practice to also replace my existing "\endnote" commands with "\pagenote"?